# Relation between Models and Templates backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, coffeescript

I have a model class named market with his corresponding template and then an other model class called match

This is the model market

```
Component = App.Components.SportJsComponent

class Component.Models.Market

  @createFromOutcome: (outcome) ->
    new @({id: outcome.market_description, description: outcome.market_description, price: outcome.price_text})

  constructor: (options) ->
    _.extend @, options

  slotDescription: ->
    @_slotDescription ||= _.first(@id.split(' '))

  domClass: ->
    _.first(@id.split(' ')).toLowerCase()

  slotNumber: ->
    _.last(@description.split(' '))

  priceFormat: ->
    (@price)
```

His template is the following

```
<li class="slotmarket">
  <p class="market <%= model.domClass() %>"><%= model.slotDescription() %><em><%= model.slotNumber() %></em><span class="price" data-price_formatted="<%= model.priceFormat() %>"></p>
</li>
```

All the data are retrieved successfully in the template, then i figured it out that i needed also the `model.priceFormat()` for an other template called match, so i created the match model class which looks exactly the same but only with the `model.priceformat()`

```
Component = App.Components.SportJsComponent

class Component.Models.Match

  @createFromOutcome: (outcome) ->
    new @({price: outcome.price_text})

  constructor: (options) ->
    _.extend @, options

  priceFormat: ->
    (@price)
```

For some reasons i can not display the `model.priceFormat()` and also the template is not rendered

```
  <div class="description"><p></p></div>
  <div class="odds"><span class="bet out_come" data-price_formatted="<%= model.priceFormat() %>"><span class="price"></span></span></div>
```

A part from not that i do not really like the solution to create a new model class file for only one model value for a template, there is a way or helper which can let me use the models of Market also for Match?

Comment: I would just overload the same model with the property value and use the same model both the templates.

Comment: I usually create a util class, and call the util class passing the data and the render the returned value. I'm using [handlerbar](http://handlebarsjs.com/) template which support the custom helpers which do the job for me

Comment: @KimGysen It does not let me do it